# Python-Nmap.0.3.4 fail to install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, nmap

I get following error when installing [python-nmap-0.3.4.tar.gz](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/):

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
D:\python\lib>cd D:\python\lib\python-nmap-0.3.4

D:\python\lib\python-nmap-0.3.4>python setup.py install
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

D:\python\lib\python-nmap-0.3.4>
```

I have python3.4 installed.

EDIT:

The problem was because of pip which I didn't mark it my installation, So I uninstall my python and then install it with pip capability and finally I install python-nmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.4 comes with pip.

Since you are using Windows, open up a command prompt and type:

`py -m pip install python-nmap`

Comment: I get same error: 
C:\Users\Zahra>py -m pip install python-nmap
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: your guid help me, I unistall and reinstall my python with pip and know I can install python-nmap on it ;)